# Cannot solve coupled stochastic differential equations and how to find correlation of solutions?

Tags: differential-equations, stochastic-calculus

I am trying to solve the equations

$x'[t] = y[t]$,

$y'[t]+(w^2+4*\gamma^2)x[t]+\gamma*y[t])=B[t]$

with the initial conditions $x[0]=0,y[0]=v_0$

This is what I have tried.

1. `$\[Omega] = Sqrt[w^2 + 4*\[Gamma]^2]$`
2. `System = {x'[t] - y[t], y'[t] + \[Omega]^2*x[t] + \[Gamma]*y[t]}`
3. `Dsolve[{x'[t] - y[t] == 0, 
   y'[t] + \[Omega]^2*x[t] + \[Gamma]*y[t] == B[t]}, {x, y}, t]`

But Mathematica 11.3 gives output `Dsolve[{-y[t] + Derivative[1][x][t] == 
   0, (w^2 + 4 \[Gamma]^2) x[t] + \[Gamma] y[t] + 
    Derivative[1][y][t] == B[t]}, {x, y}, t]`

I would like to get expressions of $x[t]$,$y[t]$ in terms of $B[t]$, and later, would like to use the fact that $<B[t]B[t']> = a_0\delta(t-t')$, (i.e. $B[t]$ is white noise) to calculate quantities like $<x[t]x[t']>$. Can that be done directly?

Comment: It's `DSolve[]`, not `Dsolve[]`.  But if it's a stochastic DE, then I think you might want a different approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @MichaelE2 alluded to in his comment, `DSolve` isn't the best approach since you've got that noise term.  Instead, take at Mathematica's [stochastic differential equation functionality](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/StochasticDifferentialEquationProcesses.html).

In particular, you can set up the system as an `ItoProcess`:

```
proc = ItoProcess[{
  \[DifferentialD]x[t] == y[t] \[DifferentialD]t,
  \[DifferentialD]y[t] == -((w^2 + 4 γ^2) x[t] + γ y[t]) \[DifferentialD]t
  + \[DifferentialD]W[t]},
  {x[t], y[t]}, {{x, y}, {0, v0}}, t, W \[Distributed] WienerProcess[0, 1]]
```

Since it's linear, you can get some analytical results:

```
Mean[proc[t]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
CovarianceFunction[proc, t′, t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

That one takes more than a minute to run and is probably not too useful.  If you assign some parameter values you get a more compact result:

```
w = 1; γ = 1;
cov = CovarianceFunction[proc, t′, t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

which you can use for plotting:

```
Plot3D[Evaluate@cov[[1, 1]], {t, 0, 5}, {t′, 0, 5}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Finally, you can simulate the dynamics with `RandomFunction`:

```
v0 = 1;
sol = RandomFunction[proc, {0, 10, 0.01}];
ListLinePlot[sol]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can solve your problem using **Green's Function** .

That means, solve your problem with righthandside `DiracDelta[t - \[Tau]]` instead of `B[t]` (there is also a build in function `GreenFunction` ...)

```
G = DSolveValue[{(w^2 + 4 \[Gamma]^2) x[t] + \[Gamma] y[t] +Derivative[1][y][t] == DiracDelta[t - \[Tau]] /. y -> (x' [#] &), x[0] == 0, x'[0] == v}, x, t] // Simplify
```

Knowing G the general solution of your problem is

```
x[t]=Integrate[G[t] B[\[Tau] ],\[Tau]]
```

which might further be considered for  "white noise"

Comment: Can you please explain what the first command does? What does `y -> (x' [#] &)` do, and why you used Dirac delta in the first equation itself? The correlation of two noises is a Dirac delta, but the noise itself is probably not a Dirac delta.

Comment: This command substitutes your first ode into the second to create one ode of second order. Try `x'[t] - y[t] == 0 /. y -> (x' [#] &) (*True*)`to confirm.

Comment: Ok. Would you please explain why you used Dirac Delta in the first equation itself?

Comment: Green's function is a method to evalaute the general solution of an ode .Knowing `x[t]` as an integral  you can calculate something like autocorrelation of x[t] to get a relationship with white noise.